# Tableau - Filter Buttons not filtering correctly

Tags: button, graph, tableau-api, visualization, analytics

I created filter buttons to use as a filter for 6 category's (measures) in Tableau Public (latest version) to filter 2 different graphs called - "Military Enrollment by Branch & War Films" as well as "Military Enrollment & Year-Over-Year Change". What I need is to be able to click on each category name (Army, Marines, War Films, etc) and for both charts to only give me data for the category selected on my dashboard. However, what is happening is that when I click on one of the buttons it displays the values for a bunch of categories instead of one and is also showing the data for specific years instead of the values for all of the years for whichever category I clicked on. Some of the years it is showing is 1980 or 1981-1983 whereas it should be displaying all the values across all years on the x-axis (from 1980-2021). It is also not showing any values for "War Films". The buttons are not working correctly and I can't find out why it is doing this.

Another issue is I can't get the "Reset Button" to work to clear all filters.

For reference I am using the worksheet called "Filter Images" for my buttons.

Attached is the workbook link: https://public.tableau.com/views/LastOne_16419877017470/Dashboard?:language=en-US&publish=yes&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link

This is the chart without any button filters applied:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZRoT.png)

Example of what it shows when I click on "Marines", it's showing me data for multiple measures when I only selected one and it's showing me data for the year 1983 instead of data for Marines from 1980-2021.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZRoT.png)

Answer (score 0):

That was VERY strange (until I looked at your data)

You only have Category values for 1983 but you also have all the Categories as separate measures as well.

You need to work on the data & I hate to have to say it now, but I think you should pivot your data and have 3 columns - Category, Year, Headcount (or whatever)  but this will mean rebuilding a LOT of your dashboard again.